# Fullcalendar - How to use list of months to navigate through calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a list of months to the left of my calendar. How can I use these month tabs to navigate through the calendar?

I am using something like this, where each anchor in #months-tab is a different month:

```
$('#months-tab a').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
```

However, it doesn't matter which month I click it will go to the next month. If the calendar is on October and I click March it won't navigate to March, it will navigate to the next month, which is November.

I know why it doesn't work but I haven't figured out to get it to work they way I need it to. Any ideas?

**Update** I began doing something along the lines of this:

```
var date = new Date();
var currM = date.getMonth();
$j('.months-tab a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newM = $j(this).attr('class');
    $j('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', newM-1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`gotoDate`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) instead of [`next`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/next/). This way you can display the calendar at the correct date.

The following javascript will work as long as you have the attribute `data-month` in each `<a>`.

Notice that [`months()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) is a zero based index, so January will have the index 0. If you have any doubts abour momentjs, please visit their [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

```
$('#months-tab a').click(function() {
    var month = $(this).attr('data-month');

    var m = moment([moment().year(), month, 1]);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', m );
});
```

You can check this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/y7vd6115/2/)** that provides a working example with the full code.

Comment: Thanks, I actually began doing something similar but without using momentjs and using classes instead of data attribute. I've updated it using what you have. 
I was trying to do ('gotoDate', m-1). I guess I will need to just change the attribute values?

Comment: Doing `m - 1` won't work because `m` is a momentjs object. From what I understand, you have the months starting by 1 (that is, 1 is January). If this is the case, you can keep the attribute values and change the line where `m` is created to `var m = moment([moment().year(), month - 1, 1]);` so the object is created with `month - 1`.